# Like box' plugin code iframe code missing

Tags: iframe, facebook-likebox

When I click the option to show the iframe code for he Facebook ['Like box' plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)
it bounces me back to the configuration page.
How can I get the iframe code?

Answer (score 0):

When I go to that like-box I'm always able to click and see the iframe codes to use.  Maybe your browser is to blame.  Try a different browser or change your current browser's settings.